# Discussion Board - Reply Email Workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, discussion-board, sharepoint-email

I have a workflow that sends a notification to selected users when a new discussion topic has been added

[image]

however when a person replies to a message i cannot get it to add the subject or the URL to where this reply has been added.

please can someone help me and show me the right steps i need to be using?